# Where is the pointer pointing?

Tags: c++

This is the defination for my class.

```
class RingBuffer {
private:
    static const size_t buffer_size;
public:
    
    std::shared_ptr<RingBufferLock> ring1_;
    std::shared_ptr<RingBufferLock> ring2_;
    RingBuffer();

};
```

I take a pointer out of the class object:

```
std::shared_ptr<RingBuffer> rings = std::make_shared<RingBuffer>();
```

Do the value of `rings.get()` function call is the same as the value of `rings_->ring1_.get()` function call ?

Comment: Welcome.   Please revise your question to be a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.  Not sure what RingBufferLock or rings_ is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rings.get()`:

This is getting raw pointer from `rings` which gives you `RingBuffer *`

`rings_->ring1_.get()`:

I suppose you mean `rings->ring1_.get()`, which first dereferences `rings` and then get raw pointer from member `ring1_`. It is the same with `rings.get()->ring1_.get()`. The final result is a `RingBufferLock *`